# Batch - How to differ between Windows 10 and Windows 11 in future versions

Tags: windows, windows-10, batch-file, windows-11, versioning

In the past i was using the major/minor number received from the ver tool in case i need to execute OS specific commands. With the release of Windows 11 it looks like this wouldn't work anymore (at least for now).

At the moment i don't check for the micro number so the script will handle windows 11 as windows 10 but i assume it could cause problems in future.

[Here is a table that shows some versions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ver_(command)#Version_list)

[image: <Here should be an preview Image that shows the version of Win10 21H1 and Win 11 21H2 but im not allowed to embed it>]

Can somebody explain how the versioning related to Windows 10 and Windows 11 will continue? (will Windows 10 stay in the range between 19043 and 22000 ?)

Comment: Not answerable until Windows 11 is released at this point.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: 22000.51 isn’t the current version of Windows 11, 22000 likely will be the major build number, given Windows 11 release is October 5th and Microsoft has already migrated the Developer Channel to next year’s feature update for Windows 11. Windows 10 21H2 (19044) is the last version of Windows 10. A build higher than 22449 will be Windows 11 22H2. 10.0.22000.x will likely change to 11.0.22000.x in the upcoming weeks (well before October 5th 2021)

Answer (score 0):

The windows 10 builds all have 19 or less in the third number: ex. 10.X.19XXX.

The Windows 11 builds will all have 22 or higher: ex 10.X.22XXX.

You can think of windows 11 as windows 10 with a higher feature set, similar to how windows 10 v1809 is a downgrade feature set from w10v1909